# Phpmyadmin ошибка #1064 с переносом БД, как исправить?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Нужно скопировать сайт на cms *WordPress* с хостинга на этот же хостинг. Скопировал сайт с файлами, всё нормально. Далее экспортировал БД в phpmyadmin: при импорте SQL на новую БД выдаёт

[image: ошибку]
С кодировкой всё нормально, и там, и там `utf8_general_ci`. Ошибка:

> MySQL said: Documentation №1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '=utf8' at line 1.

Как это исправить?

Comment: А вы открыли и посмотрели `export` `sql` файл? там есть да такая фраза ? `'=utf8'`

Comment: Там нет такой фразы, но есть utf8mb4, при её переименовании на utf8, появляется ошибка: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-

INSERT INTO `wp_nextend2_section_storage` (`id`, `application`, `section`, `r' at line 1

Comment: Полную строку приведите, что вы там меняли. Вообще-то, так не делают. Вы в вопросе ни словом не обмолвились о том, что крячили sql файл. То есть, просто водите за нос отвечающих и заставляете их ломать голову над другой проблемой. Отдельно очень хочется узнать, зачем менять utf8mb4 на utf8 с высокой вероятностью поломать сайт.

Comment: Тут почитайте https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Comment: KAGG Design, я ничего не менял в sql, и выдавало такую ошибку. После того как изменил, ошибка осталась, ещё и добавились новые.

Comment: KAGG Design, где я такое писал, что изначально что-то менял? Я ответил, что при редактировании sql выходит тоже выходит ошибка, но она другая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно скопировать сайт на cms WordPress с хостинга на этот же хостинг.

Для этого НУЖНО воспользоваться спец средствами, а не так как ты делаешь. Плагинами для миграции (напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) или скриптом https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Подробнее см [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку решил, написав в поддержку компании, где находится сервер. Там переустановили php, и ошибка пропала, дамп БД после экспорта стал небитым.